# Tag Conventions

Tags: php, mysql, tags

Currently, these are the preparations I'm making:

1. Convert to lowercase.
2. Strip HTML tags.
3. Check if tag already exists

Are there any other things that I consider?

**note:** Tags may be in Arabic.

here the method i use

```
function sanitize_tag($tag){

//strip slashes
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $tag = stripslashes(trim($tag));
} 
//Remove white spaces
$tag = preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ',$tag);
$tag = trim($tag);
$tag = ltrim($tag);
$tag=filter_var($tag, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
return $tag;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to implement a `FULLTEXT` tag searching scheme (like [`mysqlicious`](http://code.google.com/p/mysqlicious/)), make sure that your tags do not include word separators.

Say, a dash (`-`) is a word separator in `MySQL`, while an underscore (`_`) is not.

So a search like this:

```
MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('+server' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

will incorrectly return `sql-server` but (correctly) will not return `sql_server`.

Comment: than you for interest 
but iam using Toxi iplementaion

Answer (score 0):

Another common practice is to **replace spaces** and **punctuation**. Beyond that, I think you've got a solid list of preperation-steps for making a site-ready tag.

Jeff and Joel recently mentioned another interesting practice during the [Stack Overflow Podcast #79](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/podcast-79/) regarding tags. While discussing [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) (MO), they relized that MO was using a tag-abbreviation setup where each tag was prepended with an abbreviated version of itself:

Rather than having the tag `statistics`, they have `st.statistics`. This allows you to quickly search for all "statistics" questions by inputting "st." as opposed to the abmiguous "statistics," which would be a candidate for partial matches, returning items like "population statistics," etc.

Comment: thank you man ,by the way iam doing tagging in arabic if you have any other comment

Answer (score 0):

Having all tags in lower case will make it easier to privent duplicates, and, as a user, I believe it's a nice feature... But it might not always please your users, for instance if the use a name as a tag.

Maybe it would be better to use the case they typed the first time they entered the tag ?

Stipping HTML tags is nice ; I would also remove spaces *(replace them by a dash, for instance)*, and other characters that don't look great in URLs, like quotes, slashes, accents *("éàèç", ...)*, ponctuation marks, ...

In any case, don't forget to escape the tags before injecting them into SQL queries or to your HTML output ;-)

Comment: by the way iam doing tagging in arabic if you have any other comment

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; sorry, I can't really help you about arabic, though :-(